# Dynamic Grid on CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="leftx">left one</div> 
<div class="rightx">right one<br><br><br></div> 
<div class="leftx">left two</div> 
<div class="rightx">right two</div> 


 .leftx{ 
float:left;
width:50%;
}

.rightx{
float:left; 
width:50%;
}
```

Hi , above code outputs like below image, What i need is,even if right side or leftside has `<br>` , another side should not be affected.

For example There should be no break space between **left one** and **left two**.It should be dynamic.thanks

**EXAMPLE :** 
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css clear so that your code becomes

```
.leftx {
float:left;    
clear: left;
width:50%;
}

.rightx {
float:right;
clear: right;
width:50%;
}
```

which can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/YphGr/